# Python timezone conversion adding minutes to the hour?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, date-conversion, python-dateutil

So I'm trying to convert a bunch of hours (10:00:00, 14:00:00, etc) from a given timezone to UTC.

When I do so, I keep maddeningly getting things back like "15:51:00".

When you get to that line, and print what value it's using, it's using something like:

```
1900-01-01 12:00:00-05:51
```

Which is fine, except for the -05:51 bit. I have no idea why that -05:51 is there, and it's causing me problems. UTC conversion is hour to hour, yes? I think it's got something to do with my timezone conversions, but I really don't get why they would be doing that.

Here's a minimal example that has the same erroneous output; it returns `15:51:00` when it should just return a flat hour, no minutes.

```
import datetime
from dateutil import tz

jj = datetime.datetime.strptime("10:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")

tzz = tz.gettz('US/Central')

def constructstring(tzz,x):
    inter2 = x.replace(tzinfo=tzz) #ERROR HAPPENS HERE (I'm pretty sure anyways)
    inter3 = inter2.astimezone(tz.tzutc())
    return inter3

print(constructstring(tzz,jj).strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: You need to use the `localize()` method, because otherwise you'll get the *historical* timezone offset.

Comment: Can you at least reduce this to a *minimal example*? We don't need all those dictionary definitions.

Comment: yea can do give me a few mins

Comment: So what does the updated code produce, and what did you expect instead?

Comment: I see `'16:00:00'`, which means I *don't see your issue*.

Comment: It says in the question that it produces "15:51:00", and I don't know why you don't see my issue, hence why I asked the question. You not seeing it is great for you, but clearly something is wrong on my end. What package versions do you have?

Comment: Python 3.7, dateutil version 2.7.5.

Comment: That I don't see the exact same offset is probably due to differences in OS. I am running this on Mac OS 10.13, and I'll have different timezone files from your system, and / or `gettz()` returns a different specific timezone class instance on your system.

Comment: mine is 3.6.6 and 2.7.3, updated to 2.7.5, and 3.7 same problem; yeah must be the timezone classes (windows 10). Hmm I'll have to figure out how to fix that I suppose.

Comment: What does `print(tzz.utcoffset(jj))` produce for you?

Comment: "(minus)1 day, 18:09:00" (it won't let me write minus one for whatever reason)

Comment: Try not to start your comment with the output, as comments with `-` or `+` at the start with a number have been problematic in the past. Right, and for `print(tzz.utcoffset(datetime.datetime.now())`?

Comment: that gives: -1 day, 18:00:00

Comment: There you go, you have historical timezone information. The offset in 1900 was not the same as it is today.

Comment: Bless you changed it to datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-01-05 08:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") and now it gives the correct output across all my data! :D (the day is immaterial so I arbitrarily picked jan 5th :P)

Comment: That's what my answer is telling you, where I use today's date to attach to a given time.

Comment: oh there's an answer? I didn't get the notification for it or see it pop like they usually do without refreshing, odd, apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying a date when you create the `jj` datetime object, so the default date of 1900-01-01 is used. Timezones are not fixed entities; they change over time, and the US/Central timezone used a different offset back in 1900.

At the very least, use a recent date, like *today* for example:

```
# use today's date, with the time from jj, and a given timezone.
datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), jj.time(), tzinfo=tzz)
```

If all you need is a *time*, then don't create `datetime` objects to store those; the `datetime` module has a dedicated `time()` object. I'd also not use `strftime()` to create objects from literals. Just use the constructor to pass in integers:

```
jj = datetime.time(10, 0, 0)  # or just .time(10)
```

Other good rules of thumb: If you have to deal with dates with timezones, try to move those to `datetime` objects in UTC the moment your code receives or loads them. If you only have a time of day, but still need timezone support, attach them to today's date, so you get the right timezone. Only convert to strings again as late as possible.